# How to create a many-to-many relationship without CASCADE in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, cascade, cyclic-reference

I am making an MVC3 web app using Entity Framework 4.1. The problem is that I have a cyclical reference and I get an exception. I understand why it is wrong so I would like to remove ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE from my many-to-many relationship. The problem is that I do not know how to do that...
That would be it for the description of my problem. Here goes my model:

Questions ->-.
       |              |
       |              |
      /|\             |
  Fields          |
       |              |
       |              |
      /|\             |
 Answers -----'

Every question has multiple fields and every field has multiple answers. When I remove a question or an answer I want to remove the corresponding answers. I think no additional work needs to be done here. However, each answer can have multiple dependent questions (every question can be dependent on many answers). This relationship is used for displaying a question only if an answer to some other question was YES for example...
Now, If I remove an answer I do not want to remove all questions that are dependent on it, only remove the dependency.

In my model Question object has:

```
' VB
Public Overridable Property AnswerDependencies As List(Of QuestionAnswer)  

// C#
public virtual List < QuestionAnswer > AnswerDependencies { get; set; }
```

and QuestionAnswer object has:

```
' VB  
Public Overridable Property DependentQuestions As List(Of Question)  

// C#  
public virtual List < Question > DependentQuestions { get; set; }
```

How to define the anticipated behaviour in OnModelCreating event in my DataContext class that has the following properties:

```
Public Property Questions As DbSet(Of Question)  
Public Property QuestionFields As DbSet(Of QuestionField)  
Public Property QuestionAnswers As DbSet(Of QuestionAnswer)
```

---

EDIT

I found a solution to my problem! I manually created QuestionAnswerDependency object, that looks like this:

```
Public Class QuestionAnswerDependency
    Inherits ModelBase

    Public Property QuestionId As Integer?
    Public Overridable Property Question As Question

    Public Property AnswerId As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Answer As QuestionAnswer

    Sub New(ByRef q As Question, ByRef a As QuestionAnswer)
        Me.New()
        Me.Question = q
        Me.Answer = a
    End Sub

    Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I made QuestionId property nullable which results in no CASCADE ON DELETE and resolves cyclical reference. Now Question and QuestionAnswer objects have a list of QuestionAnswerDependency objects:

```
Public Overridable Property QuestionAnswerDependencies As List(Of QuestionAnswerDependency)
```

I think EF cannot automatically do what I want, but let me know if you have an idea on how to achieve that without creating "an in-between-object".